# Mirroring apt repository over ssh

Tags: debian, apt, repository, apt-cache, apt-mirror

We have a apt repository running to distribute upgrades for our software. The repository is accessed over ssh and a public key authentication:

```
deb ssh://repo.server.com/dist stable
```

As the download connection from Europe to America is really slow, I thought about setting up a mirror of the repository. I was wondering what the best practice in that case is. I tried setting up a mirror with apt-mirror, but it seems like this doesn't support ssh. I looked into apt-cacher but it seems like that doesn't really fit my needs.

Can I just rsync all files from the repository and then create a new apt repo?

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you just rsync the entire thing via SSH?  You don't really need to create a *new* repository, you just need some way of directing your clients to use the local mirror instead of the remote one.

The entire Debian/Ubuntu mirror system is based entirely on rsync, so there's not really anything stopping you from just using rsync.

Comment: So I just rsync the whole directory and then replace
   deb ssh://repo.server.com/dist stable
with
   deb ssh://repo.newserver.com/dist stable
in the corresponding mirror.list?

Comment: You don't need to replace anything, just rsync everything.

Comment: And do I really need to rsync everything, its about 200GB. Can I only sync some parts of it?